# Must neutrinos move at a fraction of speed of light?

Tags: mass, speed-of-light, speed, neutrinos, physical-constants

Although it is debunked that neutrinos can move at superluminal speed that is faster than the speed of light in a vacuum, we know that it travels at slightly less than speed of light. I'm wondering why must the neutrinos go at that speed? Is it a constant for each of the three flavors?

Comment: Since they have mass, they travel at sub-luminal speed.

Answer (score 3):

Neutrinos should be no different than any other massive particle: their speed varies with their energy. The only problem is that we cannot check that fact experimentally: neutrinos are always produced with enough energy that their speed is indistinguishable from the speed of light because their mass is so tiny.

A bit more numerically, a particle of masse $m$ with an energy $E$ has a speed

$$v=\sqrt{1-\left(\frac{m}{E}\right)^2}.$$

Thus if $m\ll E$, then $v\lesssim 1$.